# a question about derived class and base class function

Tags: c++, windows, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an exercise where I need to make a base class and a derived class. base class is called MyPoint( has x and y coordinate) and derived class is ThreeDPoint( has x,y,z). Both classes have their own distance function to calculate between two point.
I have actually manage to make it work by doing making the distance function in the base class stated as virtual.
This is the function in the base class:

```
double MyPoint::distance(const MyPoint& p2) {
return sqrt(pow(p2.getX() - getX(),2) + pow(p2.getY() - getY(),2));}
```

and this is the one in the derived class

```
double ThreeDPoint::distance(const ThreeDPoint& p2) {
return sqrt(pow(p2.getX() - getX(), 2) + pow(p2.getY() - getY(), 2)
    + pow(p2.getZ() - getZ(),2));}
```

but then I realised that the exercise specifically said that the function in derived class pass the MyPoint parameter as reference just like the one in the base class. `distance (const MyPoint &)`

But by doing this I cannot call the p2.getZ()(a getter that I made in the derived class). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Currently the question is unclear

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thank you for responding,I have edited the post. I hope it can make it clearer

Comment: Cast the `MyPoint` to a `ThreeDPoint`. If you can't cast it successfully, throw an exception or return an appropriate error.